# How to convert user timezone to UTC?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the TimeIt code on my site, it can be found here: http://codegen.in/timeit/

This is the direct link to the code: https://res.cloudinary.com/vsevolodts/raw/upload/v1503371762/timeit.min.js

It looks like this:

```
//version 3. 2017-08-13
function timeit() {
  var next_run_array = []; //array of dates/time on a page used to rerun function if a change should happen during the session
  var curDate = new Date();
  Date.prototype.yyyymmdd = function() {
var mm = this.getMonth() + 1;
var dd = this.getDate();
return [this.getFullYear(),
  (mm > 9 ? '' : '0') + mm,
  (dd > 9 ? '' : '0') + dd
].join('-');
  };
  var curDateYMD = curDate.yyyymmdd();

  $('.timeit').each(function() {
var end = $(this).data('end'),
  start = $(this).data('start');
//check if date or time value has valid format and push it to the list of refresh anchors
var startDate = checkdate(start, this);
var endDate = checkdate(end, this);
nextrun(startDate);
nextrun(endDate);

//add a datetime when the page needs to be refreshed (now+24 hrs time span only)
function nextrun(date) {
  var nextruntimeout = date - curDate;
  if (nextruntimeout < 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 && nextruntimeout > 1000) {
    next_run_array.push(nextruntimeout);    
  }
}

// Main Function 
//check if the evend outside of a desired time span
if (((startDate < endDate) && (startDate > curDate || endDate < curDate)) ||
  ((startDate > endDate) && (startDate >= curDate) && (endDate <= curDate))
) {
  $(this).addClass('hidden');
} else {
  $(this).removeClass('hidden');
}

//Support Functions
//correct data creation from a string. accepted format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM
function parseISO8601(d) {
var isoExp = /^\s*(\d{4})-(\d\d)-(\d\d)?.(\d\d)?.(\d\d)\s*$/,
    date = new Date(NaN), 
    datenew,
    month,
    dateString=d.substr(0, d.indexOf(' ')); 
    parts = isoExp.exec(d);

if(parts) {  
  month = +parts[2];
  date.setFullYear(parts[1], month - 1, parts[3]);
  if(month != date.getMonth() + 1) {
    date.setTime(NaN);
  }
  date = new Date(parts[1], month - 1, parts[3],  parts[4], parts[5])
}
return date;
  }

  //unification of the date string to the format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM
function checkdate(date, obj) {
  if (date) {
    //check if only time is set (HH:MM); if so, add today's date 
    if (String(date).length < 6 && String(date).indexOf(":") > -1) {
      date = curDateYMD + ' ' + String(date);
    }
    //check if only date is set; if so add 00:00 to the end of date
    if (String(date).indexOf(":") == -1) {
      date = date + ' 00:00';
    }
    //check if date is valid (avoid valid time)
    var res = date.split(":"),
      h = String(res.slice(0, 1)),
      hours = h.substr(h.length - 2),
      minutes = res.slice(1);
    var timetest = (hours < 24 && minutes < 60) ? true : false;

    //check if date is could be created from a value; if fails try to parse a string to a format
    var returndate = new Date(date);
    if (returndate == 'Invalid Date') {
      var returndate = parseISO8601(date);
    };


    if (returndate == 'Invalid Date' || !timetest) {
      //highlight the element if the is an error. use own \.error class if needed
      $(obj).addClass("error").attr('title', '"' + date + '" date is incorrect; please use YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM format');
    }
    return returndate.getTime();
  } else {
    //if datetime is not set, just return current date-time
    return curDate.getTime();
  }
}
  });

  /* Schedule next runs */
  if (next_run_array.length > 0) {  
var nextruntime = Math.min.apply(null, next_run_array);
console.log("next run of timeit function is in " +  nextruntime / 1000 + "seconds");
setTimeout(function() {
  timeit();
}, nextruntime);
  }
}
    timeit();

(
```

Then you just put the embed code:

```
<div class="timeit" data-start="2019-02-15" data-end="2019-07-25 23:59">
    This content will be shown between 2019-02-15 - 2019-07-25
</div>...<script src="/js/timeit.js"></script>
```

The idea is: my content is being shown between a certain period of time. I would like it to work with the UTC time zone, but right now the code is getting the date/hour info from the user's local time zone. So my content becomes available for example not at 8 AM UTC, but at 8 AM of the user's local time zone. I would like to change that.

I really, really tried to work this out on my own, but I guess this is beyond my skill set (which is pretty low). I'm confused by all the info about those ISO 8601, new Date, Date, I can't really find where it says "get the time from this source" to replace it with "get it from UTC". So - if any of you would just take a look at it and tell me what to put where, I would be extremely grateful.

Thank you all for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't use server-side scripting because of Weebly... You will have to rely on the client's clock which can be tweeked. And the `hidden` class can easily be removed... But it seems you don't have the choice.

Now, I will suggest you to forget about the [`TimeIT`](http://codegen.in/timeit/) plugin.

When it comes to dates in JavaScript/jQuery, I always recommand the use of [moment.js](https://momentjs.com) which is really easy to use (you won't have to perform complex caluculations anymore) and fully documented, so you can do whatever you wish.

Here, content hiding based on start/end dates in data attributes would look like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var utc_date = moment().utc().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");  // Client's date/time in UTC

  $(".timeit").each(function(){
    
    var start = moment($(this).data("start")).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");    
    var end = moment($(this).data("end")).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");

    console.log((utc_date>start && utc_date<end)?"Content displayed":"Content hidden");
    
    $(this).addClass("hidden"); // Hide content by default
    if(utc_date>start && utc_date<end){
      $(this).removeClass("hidden");  // Show content if now is between start/end dates
    }
    
  });

}); // ready
```

```css
.hidden{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>

<div class="timeit" data-start="2019-02-15" data-end="2019-07-25 23:59">
  This content will be shown between the dates in data attributes
</div>
```

You can try it in [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/omdLbp?editors=1011)... Change the start date and hit "Run". I left some console logs so you can understand what is going on.

For more, explore [moment.js documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/).

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate you are taking your time to look into this. Unfortunately, I ran the code, but it still doesn't work with UTC time. It was 12:39 here in Poland, so 11:39 in the UK. I changed the start date to 2019-02-11 11:41 so the content shouldn't be visible for the next 2 minutes, but it was anyways.

Comment: Sorry for that... I changed the comparison so it compares strings intead of date objects. And I also reversed the logic. I guess I was tired yesterday! lol